# WebBrowser option greyed out in toolbox (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to add a web browser to my form but it won't let me. I'm new to VS and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Screen-shot:

[image: VS2019]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

I think some of the controls do not work with Core yet.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/

When creating the project, select `Windows Form (.NET Framework)` instead of just `Windows Form`.

If this is not the issue try the following:

1. Right click on the Toolbox windows and choose `Reset Toolbox`, restart the VisualStudio.
2. Right click on the Toolbox windows and choose `Choose Items…`, under `.NET Framework Components` tab and make sure the `WebBrowser` option is checked.
3. Re-run the VisualStudio 2019 installer as administrator, click the icon beside `Launch` and choose `Repair`.